# Flask_SQLAlchemy Cannot reflect Database like SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to connect Foreigner Database to a `python-Flask` app using `Flask_SQLALchemy`

I looked everywhere including the [FLASK_SQLALCHEMY official doc](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/) 
I've been looking everywhere over the internet for the past 4 days for any tutorial that feature's `FLASK_SQLALCHEMY` Library in `ORM` without a luck

i kept looking over the [SQLAlchemy Reflecting doc](http://%20http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/reflection.html) but I got confused on decide-ding what to do next

here is my flask code:

```
Base = automap_base()
xDB = 'postgres://****'
engine = db.create_engine(xDB)
metadata = db.MetaData()
Session = db.sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = db.scoped_session(engine)
Base.metadata.reflect(engine)

y = [db.Table(table,metadata,autoload=True,autoload_with=engine) for
             table in engine.table_names()]
```

I've tried to query in many different ways based on what I've read over many sources none of them worked with `Flask_SQLAlchemy`

**attempt #1 :**

```
t = db.select('test1').limit(10)
    engine.execute(t).fetchall()
```

**output :**

> t = SELECT test1.id, test1.name
>       FROM test1
>        LIMIT :param_1

**attempt #2 :**

```
t = db.session.query([test1])
```

**output:**

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: SQL expression, column, or mapped entity expected - got '[Table('test1', MetaData(bind=None), Column('id', INTEGER(), table=, nullable=False, server_default=DefaultClause(, for_update=False)), Column('name', VARCHAR(), table=, nullable=False), schema=None)]'

i thought it's already mapped ..since `autoLoad = True` , `Base = automap_base()` and `Base.metadata.reflect(engine)`

**attempt #3 :**

```
t = metadata.tables['test1']
```

**output:**

> KeyError: Table('test1', MetaData(bind=None), Column('id', INTEGER(), table=, nullable=False, server_default=DefaultClause(, for_update=False)), Column('name', VARCHAR(), table=, nullable=False), schema=None)

what i don't understand their `metadata` is already defined up as `metadata = db.MetaData()`

I can't find anything for Flask_SQLAlchemy old or new but i can see some resources for SQLAlchemy that doesn't work for `Flask_SQLAlchemy` Library , could someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

don't use the `Flask_SQLAlchemy` and use the regular `SQLAlchemy`